# Tag or Label software for Employee Skills?

Tags: human-resources

I'm looking for some free or open source software to help me track employee skills. I frequently have to assign trouble tickets to team members, and with a large team it gets tough to know who knows what. Ideally, a simple list of employees and managers where they can chose from a curated list of tags which would help me assign work. For example, John Smith might be an expert in HIPAA and GDPR, And Jane Doe might be an expert in GxP security and compliance. Someone else might be an expert in AI/ML or image processing. The perfect solution would be something online where I can define a list of tags, users can select those that apply or recommend new ones, and I can search by tags or see an overview of all employee skills.

Suggestions?

Comment: Can I suggest that as well as letting team members tag themselves for what they are currently good at having a separate set of tags for "would like to learn" - then you can possibly pair a good at _X_ with a like to learn _X_ for some on the job training.

Comment: @SteveBarnes that would be great as well!  Good suggestion.