# Looking for skill matrix/database software

Tags: windows, web-apps, knowledge-organization, knowledge-base, intranet

I am working in a quickly growing software company that exists for many years with 50+ developers. We have experts in many sections and plan to build something like a skill matrix so that people looking for help can easily find the right person for a problem.

I already found 2 topics here but sadly there was no helpful reply yet:

[Tag or Label software for Employee Skills?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/51033/tag-or-label-software-for-employee-skills)
[Free skills/qualifications database](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/60467/free-skills-qualifications-database)

The software may be a commercial product. It may be a web based solution or must work on Windows clients. It should meet the following requirements:

- Developers should be able to add/edit their expertise, rate their level of skill and upload a photo.
- It should provide an easy to use interface for people seeking for help by using simple words or tags.

What I found so far is [Skill Matrix included in Valamis](https://www.valamis.com/documentation/skill-matrix), but its objective seems to be a bit different to what we want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research I think I found a product that meets our requirements pretty good. As a bonus it perfectly integrates into Microsoft Teams: [SkillerBee](https://www.skillerbee.com/).

Another product that sounds promising is [SkillsApp](http://www.skillsapp.com/).